# Google charts error:Cannot read property 'length' of undefined; Debugging error in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

The following code works fine as a independant page as itself. But if incorporated into my PHP web app, it throws error. How to debug if the error happens in the google chart JS?
Any suggestions will be helpful

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
  </head>

  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
   <div id="myGraphLabel" onclick="drawColumnChart();">
        My Column Chart
    </div>
    <div id="myColumnChart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});

      function drawColumnChart() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
        data.addRows(2);
        data.setValue(0, 0, 'Work');
        data.setValue(0, 1, 11);
        data.setValue(1, 0, 'Eat');
        data.setValue(1, 1, 2);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('myColumnChart')).
            draw(data, {title:"So, how was your day?"});
      }   
    </script>
</html>
```

**Error in Chrome:** It displays "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined", With a red background in the container

**Error in Firefox:** Throws error in Firebug console as: 
b[c] is undefined
http://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/97e6275dc5c50efe5944ddda289e59d2/format+en,default,corechart.I.js
Line 785

Comment: The code you provided works fine - what do you mean by **incorporate into PHP**?

Comment: I meant in my .ctp file. Sorry for the lack of clarity. I did figured it out that, due to inclusion of prototype-1.6.0.2.js, it is not working. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer will apply if you are using the Prototype JS framework. (I don't see it here, but it might have been excluded).

There is a ticket open for this issue on the Google Visualization API [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=501).

One potential issue is that there might be a conflicting version of prototype or some other library being included.

Alternately, the reduce function may need to be redefined:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Array.prototype.reduce = undefined;
</script>
```

[Note: I had this issue in the past, and this led to the solution.  I am experiencing this issue a second time, but the original solution is not working for this new issue. Your mileage may vary.]

Comment: The problems that may have applied to the Google Visualization API in 2011 in combination with the Prototype JS framework (or other similar systems) are likely to be different now.  In any event, the workaround of forcing Array.prototype.reduce to be undefined is bound to cause problems, and indeed, your code is very likely to fail now.

Comment: Suddenly i got this error. It was work from last 1 year. I have tried this but it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

In my web app, I had included 'prototype-1.6.0.2.js', which created this error !
If I exclude 'prototype-1.6.0.2.js', everything runs great !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where Google chart tools and Prototype library conflicted. I upgraded Prototype from version 1.6.1 to 1.7.1 and the problem was gone.