# google visualization + jboss seam 2

Tags: google-visualization, jboss-seam

I'm trying to use google visualization api in jboss seam 2 project.

I have created a simple example which is actually taken from [Google Quick Start page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start).

```
<html>
   <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
    // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
    // draws it.
    function drawChart() {

       // Create the data table.
       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
       data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
      data.addRows([
        ['Mushrooms', 3],
        ['Onions', 1],
        ['Olives', 1],
        ['Zucchini', 1],
        ['Pepperoni', 2]
      ]);

       // Set chart options
       var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

       // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
       var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open it as file in web browser it works nicely. But when I put it to my Jboss Seam 2 project and open in web browser, it generates an error message "b[c] is undefined" on red background.

And here what I see when I open page source in browser:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>

     <script src="/MCMS/a4j/g/3_3_3.Final/org/ajax4jsf/framework.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/MCMS/a4j/g/3_3_3.Final/org/richfaces/ui.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <link class="component" href="/MCMS/a4j/s/3_3_3.Final/org/richfaces/skin.xcss/DATB/eAGTKJ8eErp8hjQADcsDKg__" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
          google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

          // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

          // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
          // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
          // draws it.
          function drawChart() {

          // Create the data table.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
          data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
 </head>

 <body>

    <div id="chart_div"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see Jboss Seam adds some other script srcs for a4j.

Is it possible that a4j javascript conflicts with google visualization api javascript?

Is there any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: If you remove the google code and just add in some standard HTML, does it work without an error? (i.e. is the error in one of the other packages perhaps?)

Comment: Yes. It works without google code. There could not be an error in other packages, because it is already a long-living project where all features of Jboss Seam (+rich faces) works nicely. And now we wanted to use google visualization inside to show some charts.

Comment: I have also found that one man had similar problem in JSF webapp https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/bRAXXqW06DA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the solution here

[Google charts error:Cannot read property 'length' of undefined; Debugging error in Google Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759231/google-charts-errorcannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-debugging-error)

and here

http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=501 .

Adding the following hack in the beginning of the script:

```
Array.prototype.reduce = undefined;
```

or more gracefully:

```
Array.prototype.reduce=function(fun){var len=this.length&#62;&#62;&#62;0;if(typeof fun!="function")throw new TypeError;if(len==0&#38;&#38;arguments.length==1)throw new TypeError;var i=0;if(arguments.length&#62;=2)var rv=arguments[1];else{do{if(i in this){var rv=this[i++];break}if(++i&#62;=len)throw new TypeError;}while(true)}for(;i&#60;len;i++)if(i in this)rv=fun.call(undefined,rv,this[i],i,this);return rv};
```

solves the problem!

Comment: The problems that may have applied to the Google Visualization API in the past in combination with other JS libraries are likely to be different now. In any event, the workaround of forcing Array.prototype.reduce to be undefined is bound to cause problems, and indeed, your code is very likely to fail now.  Please don't do this.  I'm not sure about the definition of reduce suggested here.